# Scrapy custom exporter

Tags: python, scrapy

I am defining an item exporter that pushes items to a message queue. Below is the code.

```
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import JsonLinesItemExporter
from scrapy.utils.serialize import ScrapyJSONEncoder
from scrapy import log

from scrapy.conf import settings

from carrot.connection import BrokerConnection, Exchange
from carrot.messaging import Publisher

log.start()


class QueueItemExporter(JsonLinesItemExporter):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        log.msg("Initialising queue exporter", level=log.DEBUG)

        self._configure(kwargs)

        host_name = settings.get('BROKER_HOST', 'localhost')
        port = settings.get('BROKER_PORT', 5672)
        userid = settings.get('BROKER_USERID', "guest")
        password = settings.get('BROKER_PASSWORD', "guest")
        virtual_host = settings.get('BROKER_VIRTUAL_HOST', "/")

        self.encoder = settings.get('MESSAGE_Q_SERIALIZER', ScrapyJSONEncoder)(**kwargs)

        log.msg("Connecting to broker", level=log.DEBUG)
        self.q_connection = BrokerConnection(hostname=host_name, port=port,
                        userid=userid, password=password,
                        virtual_host=virtual_host)
        self.exchange = Exchange("scrapers", type="topic")
        log.msg("Connected", level=log.DEBUG)

    def start_exporting(self):
        spider_name = "test"
        log.msg("Initialising publisher", level=log.DEBUG)
        self.publisher = Publisher(connection=self.q_connection,
                        exchange=self.exchange, routing_key="scrapy.spider.%s" % spider_name)
        log.msg("done", level=log.DEBUG)

    def finish_exporting(self):
        self.publisher.close()

    def export_item(self, item):
        log.msg("In export item", level=log.DEBUG)
        itemdict = dict(self._get_serialized_fields(item))
        self.publisher.send({"scraped_data": self.encoder.encode(itemdict)})
        log.msg("sent to queue - scrapy.spider.naukri", level=log.DEBUG)
```

I'm having a few problems. The items are not being submitted to the queue. Ive added the following to my settings:

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    "queue": 'scrapers.exporters.QueueItemExporter'
}

FEED_FORMAT = "queue"

LOG_STDOUT = True
```

The code does not raise any errors, and neither can I see any of the logging messages. Im at my wits end on how to debug this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think writing an item pipeline would be simpler for this purpose, and involve less boilerplate code, which is a potential source for mistakes. So I would refactor your code to work as a pipeline, instead of a custom item exporter. See [item pipeline doc](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)

Comment: Ive already written a pipeline, but my thinking was, since this is how I want my output from the scraper, the exporter would be a better place to put it.

Comment: @zsquare, any success in with this problem? I know it's a old post but what did you do?

Answer (score 5):

"Feed Exporters" are quick (and somehow dirty) shortcuts to call some "standard" item exporters.  Instead of setting up a feed exporter from settings, hard wire your custom item exporter to your custom pipeline, as explained here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters :

```
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import XmlItemExporter

class MyPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        ...
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        ...

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.exporter = QueueItemExporter()
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # YOUR STUFF HERE
        ...
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

Comment: This seems promising. Anyone tested it?

Comment: What's "dirty" about them?  I'm new to Scrapy and asking myself the same question as @zsquare's OP, and I must say his comment, "my thinking was, since this is how I want my output from the scraper, the exporter would be a better place to put it," mirrors my own line of thinking.

Answer (score 2):

*Tip*: Good example to start from is [Writing Items to MongoDb](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb) from official docs.

I've done a similar thing. I've created a pipeline that places each item into an S3-like service (I'm using Minio here, but you get the idea). It creates a new bucket for each spider and places each item into an object with a random name.
Full source code can by found in [my repo](https://bitbucket.org/drozdyuk/scrapy_quotes).

Starting with simple quotes spider from the tutorial:

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
                    'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                    'text':quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                    'author':quote.css('span small::text').extract_first(),
                    'tags':quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract()
                    }
        next_page = response.css('li.next a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

In `settings.py`:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy_quotes.pipelines.ScrapyQuotesPipeline': 300,
}
```

In `scrapy_quotes/pipelines.py` create a pipeline and an item exporter:

```
import uuid
from StringIO import StringIO
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import BaseItemExporter
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.utils.python import to_bytes
from scrapy.utils.serialize import ScrapyJSONEncoder

class S3ItemExporter(BaseItemExporter):
    def __init__(self, bucket, **kwargs):
        self._configure(kwargs)
        self.bucket = bucket
        kwargs.setdefault('ensure_ascii', not self.encoding)
        self.encoder = ScrapyJSONEncoder(**kwargs)

    def start_exporting(self):
        self.client = connect()
        create_bucket(self.client, self.bucket)

    def finish_exporting(self):
        log.msg("Done from S3 item exporter", level=log.DEBUG)

    def export_item(self, item):
        log.msg("S3 item exporter got item: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        itemdict = dict(self._get_serialized_fields(item))
        data = self.encoder.encode(itemdict)
        size = len(data) 
        object_data = StringIO(data)
        name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        put_object(self.client, self.bucket, name, object_data, size)  


class ScrapyQuotesPipeline(object):
    """Export scraped items, to different buckets,
    one per spider"""
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        self.exporter = S3ItemExporter(spider.name)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item

# S3 Related
from minio import Minio
import os
from minio.error import ResponseError
def connect():
    return Minio('192.168.1.111:9000',
            access_key='0M6PYKBBAVQVQGVWVZKQ',
            secret_key='H6vPxz0aHSMZPgagZ3G0lJ6CbhN8RlTtD78SPsL8',
            secure=False)

def create_bucket(client, name):
    client.make_bucket(name)

def put_object(client, bucket_name, object_name, object_data, size):
    client.put_object(bucket_name, object_name, object_data, size)
```

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem, although being probably some version updates ahead. The little detail that solved it for me was setting `FEED_URI = "something"` in `settings.py`. Without this, the entry in `FEED_EXPORTERS` wasn't respected at all.