# Scrapy: Multiple uploads per item to S3 from Scrapy

Tags: amazon-s3, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

My question is related to uploading multiple fields from the `scrapy.Item` value that we get to S3 buckets. I see that it is possible to use feed exports to write all items to a single file with various formats by specifying the bucket url. My requirement is as below:

If my item has multiple fields as below, I would like to upload each of these fields (which can be html or md files) as separate objects to S3 buckets. I found something similar where I could write a custom exporter using the `boto3` package for the s3 connection and do a per item upload as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41973194

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class CustomItem(Item):
    field_one = Field()
    field_two = Field()
```

My question was whether there is a more native way to do this in Scrapy such as using feed exports or if there is any better way than writing custom exporters.